# Generating Models based of other models ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

So I have a model of Items with the following fields:

- Name (string)
- Description (text)
- Hider (string)
- Seeker (string)
- Long (float)
- Lat  (float)
- Keyword (string)
- Found (boolean)

Highscore should have the following fields:

-Username (name)
 -Points (int)

I want to create a model of highscores that will iterate the Item model and find entiers that have the boolean being true. Then add the seeker to the highscore table with a point. If the user already exists then, just add an extra point to his entry.

How would I go about designing this type of database...

Comment: What do you mean by "If the user already exists then, just add an extra point to his entry.". When it decides to iterate again? And what point in his entry?

Comment: If the user has already been added to the highscore table. It should iterate each time the found option has been changed from false to true . (as it will always be false when a new entry is created) A point means a score. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will never suggest **iterating** approach here. This is database we are talking about, and linear iteration over the data is unrealistic.

What you can do is use `Observer`. Read about them here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

With this, you can check at the `save` and `update` callbacks and depending upon your boolean value, you can create/update the HighScore record.

Comment: Oh thats cool! 
Let me just write the logic.
You create an Obeserver that observes the item model.
When something is updated in the model
you can check that the found opition is true
if it is true create a new entry in the highscores model

Comment: Exactly. And this is a beautiful of doing this job.